# How to search CSV file with multiple search criteria and print row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a .csv file with about 1000 rows which looks like:

```
id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address,birthday
1,Ced,Begwell,cbegwell0@google.ca,Male,134.107.135.233,17/10/1978
2,Nataline,Cheatle,ncheatle1@msn.com,Female,189.106.181.194,26/06/1989
3,Laverna,Hamlen,lhamlen2@dot.gov,Female,52.165.62.174,24/04/1990
4,Gawen,Gillfillan,ggillfillan3@hp.com,Male,83.249.190.232,31/10/1984
5,Syd,Gilfether,sgilfether4@china.com.cn,Male,180.153.199.106,11/07/1995
```

What I have for code so far will ask for input, then go over each row and print the row if it contains the input. Looks like so:

```
import csv

# Asks for search criteria from user

search = input("Enter search criteria:\n")

# Opens csv data file

file = csv.reader(open("MOCK_DATA.csv"))

# Go over each row and print it if it contains user input.

for row in file:
    if search in row:
        print(row)
```

What I want for end result, and what I'm stuck on, is to be able to enter more that one search criteria seperated by a "," and it will search and print those rows. Kind of like a way to filter the list.

for expample if there was multiple "David" that are "Male" in the file. I could enter : David, Male

It would then print all the rows that match but ignore those with a "David" thats is "Female".

Comment: I know this is a python question, but `grep David file.csv | grep Male`?

Answer (score 1):

You can split the input on the comma then check to make sure each field from the input is present on a given line using `all()` and list comprehensions.

This example uses a simplistic splitting of the input, and doesn't care *which* field each input matches. If you want to only match to specific columns, look into using `csv.DictReader` instead of `csv.reader`.

```
import csv
# Asks for search criteria from user
search_parts = input("Enter search criteria:\n").split(",")
# Opens csv data file
file = csv.reader(open("MOCK_DATA.csv"))
# Go over each row and print it if it contains user input.
for row in file:
    if all([x in row for x in search_parts]):
        print(row)
```

Comment: This is the closest to what I'm looking for. Thanks!!! Any chance you would know how to code it so that I would only have to enter part of a string to find the row? For example, instead of searching for the entire "14/05/1995" to bring up matching rows, I would only input "1995" and it would bring up all rows with 1995?

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, this is possible with `pandas`.

I have modified your data slightly to demonstrate a simple query.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,ip_address,birthday
1,Ced,Begwell,cbegwell0@google.ca,Male,134.107.135.233,17/10/1978
2,Nataline,Cheatle,ncheatle1@msn.com,Female,189.106.181.194,26/06/1989
3,Laverna,Hamlen,lhamlen2@dot.gov,Female,52.165.62.174,24/04/1990
4,David,Gillfillan,ggillfillan3@hp.com,Male,83.249.190.232,31/10/1984
5,David,Gilfether,sgilfether4@china.com.cn,Male,180.153.199.106,11/07/1995""")

# replace mystr with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(mystr)

# retrieve user inputs
first_name = input('Input a first name\n:')
gender = input('Input a gender, Male or Female\n:')

# calculate Boolean mask
mask = (df['first_name'] == first_name) & (df['gender'] == gender)

# apply mask to result
res = df[mask]

print(res)

#    id first_name   last_name                     email gender  \
# 3   4      David  Gillfillan       ggillfillan3@hp.com   Male   
# 4   5      David   Gilfether  sgilfether4@china.com.cn   Male   

#         ip_address    birthday  
# 3   83.249.190.232  31/10/1984  
# 4  180.153.199.106  11/07/1995
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I'm not too familiar with pandas but if it's the only way to do it i'll give it a shot. I'm looking for a way to get this to work so that it asks for user input so the search criteria can vary from one or multiple keywords everytime the program runs. If you can give me an example on how to do that... thta would be awesome. :)

Answer (score 0):

While you could just check if the strings `"David"` and `"Male"` exist in a row, it would not be very precise should you need to check column values. Instead, read in the data via `csv` and create a list of `namedtuple` objects that store the search value and header name:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import csv
data = list(csv.reader(open('filename.csv')))
search = namedtuple('search', 'value,header')
searches = [search(i, data[0].index(b)) for i, b in zip(input().split(', '), ['first_name', 'gender'])]
final_results = [i for i in data if all(c.value == i[c.header] for c in searches)]
```